# Plotting an Imbalanced Dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset which is highly imbalanced. I have put the labels and their corresponding counts into a pandas dataframe as follows:

```py
lbl = ['NOT', 'OFF', 'TIN', 'UNT', 'IND', 'GRP', 'OTH']
count = [7626816, 1446580, 147955, 40772, 93638, 16768, 3396]
df = pd.DataFrame({'label':lbl, 'count':count})
```

```
    label   count

0   NOT     7626816
1   OFF     1446580
2   TIN     147955
3   UNT     40772
4   IND     93638
5   GRP     16768
6   OTH     3396
```

I would like to show this imbalance using a good visualization method. With my limited knowledge of plotting styles and `matplotlib`, here is what I have come up with so far.

First, a bar plot with `sns.countplot` results in the smaller classes to not show up at all in the plot. And in `plt.pie` , the classes are too close to each other to make any sense.

[image: bar plot]
[image]

```py
#pieplot
colors = ["#E13F29", "#D69A80", "#D63B59", "#AE5552", "#CB5C3B", "#EB8076", "#96624E"]

plt.pie(
    df['count'],
    labels = df['label'],
    shadow = False,
    colors = colors,
    startangle=90,
    autopct='%1.1f%%'
)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pie plot]

How do I plot this dataset so that it represents the imbalance properly? What type to plot should be used?

Comment: Perhaps you would try and use a logarithmic scale on the Y-axis.. `plt.yscale('log')
` this would look nicer in the barplots

Comment: A common solution is to use "broken axes" where the top value is shown with a different scale that the other ones. see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html

Comment: @RoyGranit Using `yscale('log')` did the job. Thanks.

Comment: @DizietAsahi Thanks. I keep "broken axes" in my arsenal for future use.